# Xamarin Maps - access google api from custom renderer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

Is there a way to access the google maps API from within a Xamarin Forms Maps custom renderer? I want to access simple things like setZoom and getZoom or add a click listener to a circle. I realize I can zoom with Xamarin's MapSpan class but I want to use many features they failed to implement within google maps API.

**UPDATE**
The ultimate goal is to create either circles or small polylines to use as extra clickable objects. I don't really want a marker because I want to dynamically color code them. I'll use these clickable objects to call code to create an interactive popup. I already have the custom renderer. I needed getZoom because I only want to show these items when a certain zoom level or higher is shown or the map will be nothing but a blob of objects.

I currently can't figure out how to add a listener to things like a circle. I'm trying to do something like "google.maps.event.addListener" and add my click event to a circle but that's not available from what I can see, neither is the API click event for a PolyLine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You will have to write your own **custom renderer** to be able to accomplish this.

In your **custom renderer** for `Android` for example you will then be able to access and instantiate something like `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap`.

You will need to add a `NuGet` for `GoogleMaps` for your `Android` project before you will be able to see the `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap` namespace etc.

By doing so you can expose as much of `GoogleMaps` as you so wish.

**Update 1:-**

To move the camera to a different zoom level on `Android` you will want to create a new `CameraPosition` object and specifiy the `Map Zoom Level` as a parameter.

You can then:-

```
var objCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(objMyCameraPosition);
```

and then finally on the `GoogleMaps` object call the `.MoveCamera(objCameraUpdate)`

Comment: Ok, I have that already. Looking at the class its a Sealed class with only a partial set of methods and properties. Example:[Register("animateCamera", "(Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdate;)V", "")]
        public void AnimateCamera(CameraUpdate update);

Comment: setZoom and getZoom are not provided.

Comment: Looks like its derived from Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.dll

Comment: @user3478586 I've updated my answer (See **Update 1**) with more detail how to set the camera to a new zoom level.

Comment: Thanks for the help...but it's still not the answer I needed. I was wanting to access the API directly. I assume this is not possible without an update to GooglePlayServices that adds all GoolgeMap properties and methods or writing my own cross platform map control all together. If you can provide a means to add a click listener to a Circle that would get me where I need to be and I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: By creating the `GoogleMaps` control you can do anything on the native platform specific layer.  What do you mean you can't access the API directly?  You are!  And yes - you can create circles if you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class which derives from MapRenderer in your .Droid project you have a property named NativeMap which is the native map control, it has all the functions on it.

BUT, you're trying to use old API's, setZoom and getZoom doesn't exist any more, instead you must use moveCamera, take a look at the map's SDK help: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

Comment: +1 for showing me I'm looking at the old API. I was already aware of NativeMap. However, its still missing things like OnPolyLineClickListener.